# Cassandra Performance SELECT by id or SELECT by nothing

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I am wondering if C*s `SELECT` speed depends on how we select whole finite tables.

For example we have this table

```
id | value
A  | x
A  | xx
B  | xx
C  | xxx
B  | xx
```

Would it be faster to get all the results if we would do
`SELECT * FROM Y WHERE id='A'`
`SELECT * FROM Y WHERE id='B'`
`SELECT * FROM Y WHERE id='C'`

or would it be faster if we would do
`SELECT * FROM Y WHERE 1`

or maybe would it be faster if we would do
`SELECT * FROM Y WHERE id IN ('A', 'B', 'C')`

Or would they be equally fast ( if we dismiss connection time )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what your column family (table) definition looks like, but your sample data could never exist like that in Cassandra.  Primary keys are unique, and if `id` is your primary key, the last write would win.  Basically, your table would look something like this:

```
id | value
A  | xx
C  | xxx
B  | xx
```

As for your individual queries...

```
SELECT * FROM Y WHERE 1
```

That might work well with 3 rows, but it won't when you have 3 million, all spread across multiple nodes.

```
SELECT * FROM Y WHERE id IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

This is definitely not any faster.  [See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26999098/is-the-in-relation-in-cassandra-bad-for-queries/27000384#27000384) as to why relying on `IN` for anything other than occasional OLAP convenience is not a good idea.

```
SELECT * FROM Y WHERE id='A'
SELECT * FROM Y WHERE id='B'
SELECT * FROM Y WHERE id='C'
```

This is definitely the best way.  Cassandra is designed to be queried by a specific, unique partitioning key.  Even if you wanted to query every row in the column family (table), you're still giving it a specific partition key.  That would help your driver quickly determine which node(s) to send your query to.

Now, let's say you *do* have 3 million rows.  For your application, is it faster to query each individual one, or to just do a `SELECT *`?  It might be faster from a query perspective, but you will still have to iterate through each one (client side).  Which means managing them all within the constraints of your available JVM memory (which probably means paging them to some extent).  But this is a bad (extreme) example, because there's no way you should ever want to send your client application 3 million rows to deal with.

The bottom line, is that you'll have to negotiate these issues on your own and within the specifications of your application.  But in terms of performance, I've noticed that appropriate query based data modeling tends to outweigh query strategy or syntactical tricks.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. You are right my example table was poorly chosen and could not exist in a real C* table. So you think `SELECT * WHERE 1` could be faster ( even if the data is spread over different nodes )? This question was asked with and Apache Spark application in mind, where i do want to transform the data. Memory should not be the problem here.

Comment: @MichaelHirn Like I said, it will depend on the nature of your application.  If I had millions of rows and had really to process through all of them, in that case I wouldn't do it id-by-id.  But if I only needed 3 or even 3000, that's a different story.  If you're using Spark on all of your rows for an OLAP process, by all means give `SELECT *` a shot and see how it does.