# Cassandra IN query not working if table has SET type column

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am new to Cassandra. I have an issue when using IN in cassandra query.

If table has no column of SET type it works.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    test_date bigint, 
    test_id bigint, 
    caption text,
    PRIMARY KEY(test_date,test_id)
);

select * from test where test_date = 2022015 and test_id IN (1,2);
```

But if I add a column of SET type f.e. **tags set** in the above table and rerun the select query, it gives error.

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
    test_date bigint, 
    test_id bigint, 
    tags set<text>,
    caption text,
    PRIMARY KEY(test_date,test_id)
);

select * from test1 where test_date = 2022015 and test_id IN (1,2);
```

> code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Cannot restrict column "test_id" by
> IN relation as a collection is selected by the query"

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why this restriction should apply particulary for collections. But in your case you can get around this issue by making the test_id part of your partition key:

`PRIMARY KEY((test_date,test_id))`

This will allow you to do IN queries as long as you specify the first part of the composite key (test_date).

Comment: It is usually not a good idea to use IN statement with partition key.

Comment: @k0ner is it because each test id will be stored in separate node because of different partition?

Comment: @tausif it is because many nodes will be involved into fulfilling this query. It might flood your cluster with queries and since it is technically a single query broken into multiple queries it might take significant time to get the answer back. For more detailed answer please refer the other post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27000384/2889288

Answer (score 3):

I think you are seeing this error due to Cassandra's underlying storage model.  When I query your `test1` table within CQLSH (with my own test data), this is what I see:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM test1;

 test_date | test_id | caption   | tags
-----------+---------+-----------+-------------------------
   2022015 |       1 | blah blah | {'one', 'three', 'two'}
   2022015 |       2 | blah blah | {'one', 'three', 'two'}

(2 rows)
```

This view gives a misleading interpretation of how the data is actually stored.  This is what it looks like when I query the same table from within cassandra-cli:

```
[default@stackoverflow] list test1;
Using default limit of 100
Using default cell limit of 100
-------------------
RowKey: 2022015
=> (name=1:, value=, timestamp=1422895168730184)
=> (name=1:caption, value=626c616820626c6168, timestamp=1422895168730184)
=> (name=1:tags:6f6e65, value=, timestamp=1422895168730184)
=> (name=1:tags:7468726565, value=, timestamp=1422895168730184)
=> (name=1:tags:74776f, value=, timestamp=1422895168730184)
=> (name=2:, value=, timestamp=1422895161891116)
=> (name=2:caption, value=626c616820626c6168, timestamp=1422895161891116)
=> (name=2:tags:6f6e65, value=, timestamp=1422895161891116)
=> (name=2:tags:7468726565, value=, timestamp=1422895161891116)
=> (name=2:tags:74776f, value=, timestamp=1422895161891116)

1 Row Returned.
```

This suggests that collection (set) values are stored as additional column keys.  A restriction on using the `IN` relation, is that it must operate on the last key (partitioning or clustering) of a primary key.  So I would guess that this is a limitation based on how Cassandra stores the collection data "under the hood."

And just a warning, but using `IN` for production-level queries is not recommended.  Some have even gone as far as to put it on the list of Cassandra anti-patterns.  My answer to this question ([Is the IN relation in Cassandra bad for queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26999098/is-the-in-relation-in-cassandra-bad-for-queries/27000384#27000384)) explains why `IN` queries are not optimal.

**EDIT**

Just to see, I tried your schema with a list instead of a set to see if that made any difference.  It still didn't work, but from within the cassandra-cli it appeared to add an additional UUID identifier to the key, and stored the actual value as the column value.  Which is different from how a set was treated...this must be how sets are restricted to unique values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Materialized View with test_id as a part of partitioning expression to satisfy your requirement if changing the PK on your base table is not an option:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test1_mv AS
SELECT * FROM test1
WHERE test_date IS NOT NULL AND test_id IS NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY((test_date,test_id));
```

Then use the Materialized View instead of the base table in your query:

```
select * from test1_mv where test_date = 2022015 and test_id IN (1,2);
```