# Cannot restrict clustering columns by in relations when a collection is selected by the query

Tags: cassandra

I am reading this article which shows how to write queries with IN clause in cassandra

https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause

I created the following table

```
create table foo2(id bigint, bid bigint, data set<bigint>, primary key (id, bid));

insert into foo2 (id, bid, data) values (1, 1, {1, 2});
insert into foo2 (id, bid, data) values (1, 2, {3, 4});
insert into foo2 (id, bid, data) values (1, 3, {5, 6});
```

Now I write the query

```
select * from foo2 where id = 1 and bid IN (1, 2, 3);
```

Cannot restrict clustering columns by in relations when a collection is selected by the query.

I googled on this error and found this

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12654

and it says that the issue is resolved in Cassandra 4.0 but I a using

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.10 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
```

Is there a workaround for this (apart from the mother of all answers for any Cassandra question `change your schema`)

Some people are pointing here : [Cassandra IN query not working if table has SET type column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28278199/cassandra-in-query-not-working-if-table-has-set-type-column)

But this does not question does not have a clearly marked answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cassandra IN query not working if table has SET type column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28278199/cassandra-in-query-not-working-if-table-has-set-type-column)

Comment: Ashraful.. that question does not have a marked answer. So you are pointing me to an unanswered question.

Comment: This is the cassandra's limitation, If you use set, list, or map in your table you can't use in clause with clustering key

Answer (score 6):

You may not like this answer but you will have to change the schema a bit to work around this issue. By using `frozen` the issue will disappear.
Note that this issue is also affecting UDT's and that for them it also get's fixed by using `frozen`.

Answer (score 4):

**Old answer:**
Using **column names** instead of `*` will solve the problem.
In your case, the query should be:
`select id,bid,data from foo2 where id = 1 and bid IN (1, 2, 3);`

**Update:**
I was wrong with previous answer, It should be a limitation of Cassandra which we can't use IN query for the cluster key when we query a collection column(**data** column). If you really need an IN query, you can change the schema of the table:

`create table foo3(id bigint, bid bigint, data set<bigint>, primary key ((id, bid)));`
(New parentheses is introduced in the key of table)

In this new schema, the partition key is group of columns **id** and **bid** which we can have IN query for partition key. Now, below query should work:
`select * from foo3 where id = 1 and bid IN (1, 2, 3);`