# DSE Cassandra 3.x delete operation

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have a table with a PRIMARY KEY of ( (A,B), C)
Partition key (A,B)
Clustering key C

My question is related to deleting from this table.

Is it efficient to use the IN clause when deleting or to issue multiple 
delete statements using the equality operation.

```
delete from table where A=xx and B IN ('a','b','c');
```

-OR-

```
delete from table where A=xx and B='a';
delete from table where A=xx and B='b';
delete from table where A=xx and B='c';
```

Is there any harm in using the IN operator as in the 1st delete statement.
There may be up to around 20 deletes in total (or 20 items in the IN clause).

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

With a few small exceptions its almost always better to use the 2nd option multiple deletes issued asynchronously instead. The coordinator of the IN clause will be put on a lot of load while the later will evenly distribute the load. Also with a TokenAware load balancer the requests will go directly to the correct replicas and can complete pretty quickly. If you are doing hundreds or more of the deletes you might wanna use a Semaphore or something though to limit number of in flight deletes, just to prevent overloading cluster.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the needs of your application.  If the delete operations are expected to be fast, then you'll probably want to run each one explicitly (second option).

On the other hand, if the delete runs as a part of a batch or cleanup job, and nobody really cares how long it takes, then you could probably get away with using `IN`.  The trick there would be in keeping it from timing-out (and as Chris indicated, putting undue load on the node).  It might make sense to break-down your groups of values for column `B`, to keep those small.  While 20 list items with `IN` isn't the *most* I've heard of someone trying, it's definitely more than I would ever use personally (I'd try to keep it smaller than 10).

Essentially, using the `IN` operator with a `DELETE` is going to be susceptible to performance issues just like it would be on a `SELECT`, as described in this answer (included here for reference):

[Is the IN relation in Cassandra bad for queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26999098/is-the-in-relation-in-cassandra-bad-for-queries/27000384#27000384)