# Cassandra Query Performance: Using IN clause for one portion of the composite partition key

Tags: cassandra, query-optimization, datastax-java-driver

I currently have a table set up in Cassandra that has either text, decimal or date type columns with a **composite partition key** of a business_date and an account_number. For queries to this table, I need to be able to support look-ups for a single account, or for a list of accounts, for a given date.

Example:

```
select x,y,z from my_table where business_date = '2019-04-10' and account_number IN ('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC')
//Note: Both partition keys are provided for this query
```

I've been struggling to resolve performance issues related to accessing this data because I'm noticing latency patterns that I am having trouble trying to understand / explain.

In many scenarios, the same exact query can be run a total of three times in a short period by the client application. For these scenarios, I see that two out of three requests will have really bad response times (800 ms), and one of them will have a really fast one (50 ms). At first I thought this would be due to key or row caches, however, I'm not so sure since I believe that if this were true, the third request out of the three should always be the fastest, which isn't the case.

The second issue I believed I was facing was the actual data model itself. Although the queries are being submitted with all the partition keys being provided, since it's an IN clause, the results would be separate partitions and can be distributed across the cluster and so, this would be a bad access pattern. However, I see these latency problems when even single account queries are run. Additionally, I see queries that come with 15 - 20 accounts performing really well (under 50ms), so I'm not sure if the data model is actually an issue.

Cluster setup:

- Datacenters: 2
- Number of nodes per data center: 3
- Keyspace Replication:local_dc = 2, remote_dc = 2

Java Driver set:

- Load-balancing: DCAware with LatencyAware
- Protocol: v3
- Queries are still set up to use "IN" clauses instead of async individual queries
- Read_consistency: LOCAL_ONE

Does anyone have any ideas / clues of what I should be focusing on in terms of really identifying the root cause of this issue?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26999098/is-the-in-relation-in-cassandra-bad-for-queries/27000384#27000384

Answer (score 7):

the use of `IN` on the partition key is always the bad idea, even for composite partition keys.  The value of partition key defines the location of your data in cluster, and different values of partition key will most probably put data onto different servers. In this case, coordinating node (that received the query) will need to contact nodes that hold the data, wait that these nodes will deliver results, and only after that, send you results back.

If you need to query several partition keys, then it will be faster if you issue individual queries asynchronously, and collect result on client side.

Also, please note that TokenAware policy works best when you use `PreparedStatement` - in this case, driver is able to extract value of partition key, and find what server holds data for it.

Comment: Thanks @alex-ott. Would you have any idea how to explain the following if the IN clause is an issue:

"However, I see these latency problems when even single account queries are run. Additionally, I see queries that come with 15 - 20 accounts performing really well (under 50ms), so I'm not sure if the data model is actually an issue."

Comment: The slow query on some partitions could be caused by several reasons: a lot of tombstones in given partition, very big partition, too many SSTables, etc. You can execute `nodetool tablestats` on given table and see what is the biggest partitions, how many tombstones were read in last requests, etc. `nodetool tablehistograms` is also useful to get statistics about high percentiles