# Performance when "findById" with "@PrimaryKeyClass"

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I want a `bulk-get` function with cassandra.

But spring-data-cassandra's "findAllById" function  not working because `Cassandra supports single-field IN queries only`.

So I try combining iteration with `findById` like this.

```
// Somekey : cassandra primary key object with @PrimaryKeyClass
List<Somekey> keys = {add some keys};

// SomeData : cassandra data
List<SomeData> datas = new ArrayList<>();

for (SomeKey : key : keys) {
  datas.add(someRepo.findById(key));
}
```

But I think it is not good at performance for the following reasons.

1. Cassandra sorts the data, but this is random access. (i think)
2. Increasing network load in proportion to `keys.size()`

How do I use `bulk-get` function with cassandra??

And, could I solve this performance problem with `ReactiveCassandraRepository`??

Comment: You should avoid using the IN operator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26999098/is-the-in-relation-in-cassandra-bad-for-queries

Comment: In my code, I think i use individual query Not IN query.

Comment: The way you do it is the correct approach. You send multiple single queries and merge the result client-side.