# spark-cassandra-connector scala update columns

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have table like this:

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|cid             |email_address |status|last_updated_dt        |created_at             |    
+----------------+--------------+------------------------------+-----------------------+
|12345-ddd-ddd   |abc@test.com  |New   |2019-12-17 22:52:02.289|2019-11-17 22:52:02.9  |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|12345-eft-xdrg  |abc@test.com  |New   |2019-12-17 22:52:02.289|2019-10-17 22:52:02.395|
+----------------+--------------+------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|23456-efes-xeg  |bdc@test.com  |New   |2019-12-17 22:52:02.289|2019-12-10 22:52:02.210|
+----------------+--------------+------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

Partitioning key is 'email_address', clustering key is 'created_at'.

I need to pull out all records for email abc@test.com and update the 'status' to 'Inactive' and 'last_updated_dt' to current timestamp, and here is my code:

```
val emails=List("abc@test.com")
sc.cassandraTable(my_keyspace, my_table)
  .select("email_address", "last_updated_dt", "status")
  .where("email_address IN ?", emails)
  .map(r => (r.getString("email_address"), Instant.now().toString(), "Inactive"))
  .saveToCassandra(my_keyspace, my_table)
```

and i got this error: `key not found: cid`

do i have to include all columns in `'.select()'` in order to update some columns? is this the right way to update existing column for rows in Cassandra?

I'm using Spark, Cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, scala.

Edit:
Figure out how to do it:

```
val selectedRows = sc.cassandraTable(my_keyspace, my_table)
  .select("email_address", "last_updated_dt", "status")
  .where("email_address IN ?", emails)

val transformedRows = selectedRows.map{item => 
  val email=item.getString("email_address")
  val lastUpdatedDt=Instant.now().toString()
  val updatedStatus="Inactive"
  (email, lastUpdatedDt, updatedStatus)
  }
transformedRows.saveToCassandra(my_keyspace, my_table, SomeColumns("email_address", "last_updated_dt", "status"))
```

Comment: Well, here be careful, i see 2 points ,which indicate something is not 100% correct. No.1 : Cassandra has primary key, which is partitioning key+clustering key. In your situation you are using IN in where clause, which is not recommended according to the official docs as it can become performance problem in the cluster (Cassandra needs to read all partitions for evaluating that). For me it seems that your structure of table is not designed in big data way, but more in relational way.

Comment: @MatusDanoczi : the primary key is email_address, would that still be a problem ?

Comment: it will work for you, only problem is that it is not optimal maybe. Can you also find out, which one is partitioning key PK and which one clustering key CK?

Comment: @MatusDanoczi: updated the post, Partitioning key is 'email_address', clustering key is 'created_at'

Comment: Ok, then seems fine, just as recommendation read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26999098/is-the-in-relation-in-cassandra-bad-for-queries, which can help you understand IN performance pittfalls in some situations.

Comment: @MatusDanoczi: thanks!