# Many simultaneous queries gocqlx

Tags: go, cql, scylla

Does gocqlx have a built in method to do many simultaneous queries?
I thought about using IN to select many different records, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27000384/9133582), it is better to use many queries than to use an IN clause.

If gocqlx doesn't have the ability to run many queries in parallel natively, how can I implement it myself most efficiently? I need to use this to make up to 100 simultaneous queries, and this process may need to be run up to 10 times a second, so about 100 * 10 = 1000 queries per second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One suggestion for a way you could run 100 simultaneous queries is to spawn 100 goroutines and then collect their results after they all run. Whether or not this will meet your 1000 QPS requirement I can't say, but you can try testing it at that QPS on your hardware to find out.

Here's what it would look like (pseudocode):

```
type queryResult struct { ... }

func doQuery(qry MyQuery, resChan chan queryResult, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
   result := // do query
   resChan <- result
   wg.Done()
}

// in main:

resChan = make(chan queryResult, len(queries))
var wg sync.WaitGroup

for _, query := range queries {
  go doQuery(query, resChan, &wg)
  wg.Add(1)
}

wg.Wait()
close(resChan)

for res := range resChan {
  // get results
}
```

If you don't need the results, you can use `sync.WaitGroup` without the result channel just to verify that all your queries have completed.

If you don't want to use up all your connections to the DB or you just don't want to have 1000 goroutines for any reason, you could use a worker pool as described here: https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools

Answer (score 0):

https://godoc.org/github.com/gocql/gocql#Session

> Session is the interface used by users to interact with the database.
>   It's safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines and a typical usage scenario is to have one global session object to interact with the whole Cassandra cluster.

Typical usage scenario is to have one Session accessed by many goroutines.