# What is the overhead of querying multiple partition keys in the same token range via IN operator in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql, database-partitioning

Usually querying multiple rows with different partition keys isn't recommended in Cassandra  because those queries might affect multiple nodes.
However, it's not clear about querying multiple partition keys which are placed in the same token range (*meaning they are stored on the same nodes*).

If the application guarantees to use partition keys from the same token range AND the load balancing strategy routes the query to the node containing that token range AND the replication factor is 1, would it be recommended to use `IN` operator over multiple partition keys? What is the overhead compared to situation when we asynchronously execute separate CQL query per partition key?
In other words, would this query be recommended (assuming `id` is the partition key and all provided partition keys belong to the same token range)?

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table WHERE id IN(1,2,3,4,5)
```

or are the below 5 queries recommended instead?

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table WHERE id=1
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table WHERE id=2
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table WHERE id=3
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table WHERE id=4
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table WHERE id=5
```

Declaimer: I'm asking this question because I do see about 20% performance improvement with Cassandra 4 using `IN` operator over multiple partition keys which are located on the same node (same token range) if compared to the situation when I perform a separate CQL query per each partition key asynchronously. That said, as usually people recommend executing a separate CQL query for different partition keys, I would like to understand the main reason why.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26999098/is-the-in-relation-in-cassandra-bad-for-queries

Answer (score 1):

The main reason why people recommend using async queries is because at low volume the queries will probably be fine. However, as the volume of requests increases, you may very well run into problems. This happens because at some point the coordinator gets bogged down doing a scatter gather (which is what happens with a cross partition query because the partitions may live on different nodes in the cluster). That scatter gather over time, as there's more data, higher volume, etc, will begin to cause timeouts because the coordinator is busy retrieving data from several different nodes.

Instead, if you do one async query, the coordinator responds, and then is ready to serve the next request. It's much easier on the coordinator and less likely to cause timeouts.